# How did the clones know it was Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, order-66

In *Revenge of the Sith*, How did the clones recognize Palpatine when he made the transmission to execute Order 66?

[image: image of clone receiving Order 66]

Palpatine was hooded and disfigured, so how did the clones know it was him? Do the inhibitor chips play a role in this or was it a secure communication channel only known by the clones?

Comment: Transmission was encrypted with Palp's private key.  Little known fact, the passphrase for his key is "PapaPalpatine"  :-)

Comment: « Pa Pa Palpatine, lover of the Naboo queen… » Er, sorry.

Comment: My impression has been that the "Order 66" was to be viewed as much a trigger phrase implanted in them as well as an actual order so they were programmed to carry it out.

Comment: I think he opened the communication by saying “Hey guys, this is Palpatine”, and then one clone trooper said “Wait wait — are you really Palpatine?”, and he said “Yes”, and the clone trooper was like “Okay, his story checks out.”

Answer (score 25):

The film's official novelisation indicates that the frequency was reserved for Palpatine.

> *“Yes, sir.” A silent buzzing vibration came from a compartment
> concealed within his armor. Cody frowned. “Go on ahead, General. We’ll
> be right behind you.”*
>
> ***That concealed compartment held a secure comlink, which was
> frequency-locked to a channel reserved for the commander in chief.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

That being said, the Clones seem to accept the order ***from whoever is using the frequency*** without question, as a result of their training/brainwashing.

> *A holoscan appeared on the palm of his gauntlet: **a hooded man.***
>
> *“It is time,” the holoscan said. “Execute Order Sixty-Six.”*
>
> ***Cody responded as he had been trained since before he’d even awakened
> in his creche-school.** “It will be done, my lord.”*
>
> *The holoscan vanished.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Let me ask you a question, isn't there an episode on Star Wars Rebels where Rex says that he, Cody and Fives have extracted their chips ?

Comment: @Machado - After Order 66, I gather.

Comment: Hm. That makes sense.